# Spaceing Issue with listings

Tags: listings

I am having a bit of trouble putting python code into a latex document using listings. The code is appearing with a large indent on the left so that it has to go onto multiple lines.

Here is an image: 
[image]

This is the code I am using to set up listings:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=L,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  language=Python,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  columns=flexible 
}

\lstset{escapechar=@,style=customc}
```

And here is how I create a listing:

```
\lstinputlisting[caption= Construction of output for \texttt{write\_dataLine}, style=customc, label= inputtottxt, firstline=27, lastline=27]{datafile.py}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you also add the contents of `datafile.py`?

Comment: Those `listings` settings don't cuase the code to be indented as much as in your screenshot. Could it be that line 27 of `datafile.py` is already indented a lot?

Comment: I unintended all of the code to try and fix the issue. Still did the same thing.